# listen for ended phone call when the USER makes the phone call

Tags: iphone, avplayer

I have an app that plays audio(a media player). When the user receives a phone call, the audio appropriately pauses then resumes when the call ends, even if the user doesn't have the media player in the foreground. The problem is when a user makes a phone call while the audio is running, the audio will pause, but not resume after the call is finished. The iPod music player implements this functionality - The main and important different between my player and the iPod one is that I am using an AVPlayer instead of an MPMediaController.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably check the [CTCallCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html) reference documentation. As far as I know it is not possible for you to resume the music, however you can do some of the stuff suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059074/how-to-resume-iphone-app-after-a-phone-call).

The suggestion is to send a notification to your user when the call has ended-as a reminder for the music.