# How should I handle incomming call in iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, object, avplayer

I am sure it is a duplicate question, but I didn't found any valid solution. I am using AVPlayer rather than AVAudioPlayer, and streaming audio files on iphone. When call interrupts my application (which is running either in background or active), then it goes into pause state. But can't play when call ended. What should I do? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Khalid Usman

Answer (score 0):

You could set a local notification that reminds the user, as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5845372/184245).